# Read longlat data realtime Firebase and implementation to map Android Studio

Tags: java, android, google-maps, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Can you help me fix this?

[image: My Firebase]

I want to read data realtime from Firebase and display markers on maps. The longlat marker data is read realtime from firebase not from the code. Firebase changed data in the maps changes too.

This is my code:

```
public class mapmotor1 extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

private GoogleMap mMap;
private FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase;
private DatabaseReference databaseReference;
private static final int LOCATION_REQUEST = 500;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_mapmotor1);

    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

    firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    databaseReference = firebaseDatabase.getReference().child("proyek-akhir-c93d7").child("1");

}

/**
 * Manipulates the map once available.
 * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
 * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
 * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
 * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
 * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
 * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
 */
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;
    firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    databaseReference = firebaseDatabase.getReference().child("proyek-akhir-c93d7").child("1");
   **//this is replaced what**
    LatLng device = new LatLng (-6.97455, 107.6326);

    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(device).title("Here"));

    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(device, 15));
    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomIn());
    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15), 2000, null);
}

@SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode){
        case LOCATION_REQUEST:
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the `proyek-akhir-c93d7` is your Firebase root, to get the latitude and longitude under the `1` node, please use the following lines of code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference oneRef = rootRef.child("1");
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        double latitude = dataSnapshot.child("latitude").getValue(Double.class);
        double longitude = dataSnapshot.child("longitude").getValue(Double.class);
        //Do what you need to do with the latitude and longitude
        Log.d("TAG", latitude + ", " + longitude);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
oneRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

The output in your logcat will be:

```
-6.97455, 107.6326
```

Comment: "oneRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);"
where is the code placed? below public void onCancelled or dataonchange ?

Comment: No, right where you see in my code, right after the last curly braces and semicolon, right? Does it work?